# Designing a web comic site, and I need help writing/finding a script that would manage the <<First <Prev Next> Latest>> system

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for a script that would

1. have a form with the fields: comic name, comic ID (like a number), date, image link to the comic, and create a page for that comic, with the URL being http://example.com/# of comic/.
2. Have a system of sending you back one comic (previous), forward one (Next), and the the first and last one.
3. Display the latest comic on the homepage, with the "next" link grayed out.

I know HTML and CSS, and am learning bits of JavaScript and PHP, so something using those technologies would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the answers you seek depend heavily on how you're going to store the pages.  In any case, your PHP code to do the links needs the following logic:

```
if($id != $minId) {
   print("a href=\"http://website.com/" . ($id - 1) . "\"><img src=\"leftArrow.gif\"/></a>", );
}
if($id != $maxId) {
   print("a href=\"http://website.com/" . ($id + 1) . "\"><img src=\"rightArrow.gif\"/></a>", );
}
```

If the current page isn't the first page, print the back arrow.  If the current page isn't the last page, then print the forward arrow (*note that I would write a function to generate the link so if the format changes you only need to change it in one place*)

How you get the $minId and $maxId depends on how you store the pages.  If you're storing them in a database, then in the code where you're generating the link, you need SELECT statements to get the min and max.  If you're storing them as files, you can do something like "ls -1 | tail -1" to get the highest number.  Or every time you create a new page, update a number in a file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is essentially a blog with images for entries. Give WordPress a try.

Comment: I was hoping this could be a wonderful learning experience for me. I just want to be pointed to a tutorial for the sort of things I'm asking about (calling images, generating pages)

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment to Chuck's answer, and the fact you just want to be pointed in the right direction, I would suggest looking at pagination in PHP as well as mod_rewrite in order to get the URLs you want.

Comment: What Saladin is referring to with mod_rewrite is the the way you configure a web server to take an address like http://website.com/35 and have it map to the file public_html/35.html or something like that.  I think you would make your life MUCH easier if you change the URL to something like http://website.com/index.php?id=35 to eliminate the need to become an Apache expert, too.  This way you have a single script that loads the content based on the id passed to it.  Much more straightforward.

Comment: @dj_segfault: You don't really have to be an Apache expert to convert website.com/index.php?id=35 to website.com/35 — that's pretty much "hello world" for mod_rewrite.